# How to replicate the functionality of the open command on Windows using a batch file?

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the open command on the mac using Windows batch scripts. Here is what I have so far in my file `open.cmd` that I have on the `PATH`:

```
echo off
IF "%1"=="" GOTO HAVE_0
IF "%1"=="." GOTO HAVE_0
IF "%2"=="" GOTO HAVE_1
GOTO ERROR

:HAVE_0
explorer %cd%
GOTO END

:HAVE_1
explorer %1

:ERROR
echo "Incorrect number of arguments."
echo "Please use the command: c:\>open <directory>"
echo "eg c:\>open ."

:END
```

Now this works. I think there must be a better way or something I've missed. Is there a better way?

My question is: **How to replicate the functionality of the open command on Windows using a batch file?**

Comment: I've never used a Mac and I don't have one available. What does the `open` command do?

Comment: Also, if you're just looking to improve code that already works, you want to post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: While this may be a good fit for CR, we would certainly like a bit more context. Also, asking "How do I do *X*" is off-topic for Code Review. If the code works as intended, then you're welcome to bring it over to CR.

Comment: cmd has [`start`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As eryksun points out, `start` is very similar to `open`.  You can shorten your script to just this:

```
@start "" %*
```

and I think it'll work mostly as you intend.  If you supply a directory as an argument, the script will open an Explorer window.  If you supply a URL, it'll open your default web browser.  If you supply a document, it'll open the document in its associated program.

(How's that for code golfing?)

Comment: Got it - I knew there was a better way.